# How can I remove an item from a list that is located just before a certain index?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to remove an item from a list; but the item I'm trying to remove is located just before an
`index('  ')`. How can I `pop()` the item from this list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [give `pop` an index as its argument](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', 'd']
>>> lst.pop(lst.index(' ') - 1)
'c'
>>> lst
['a', 'b', ' ', 'd']
```

Of course you have to make sure that the item `' '` has an index >= 1 before. If you don't need the removed value, you can use `del lst[index]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Items can be deleted with `del`:

```
del my_list[my_list.index(" ") - 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> liste = [12, 5, 9, " ", 8]
>>> liste.pop(liste.index(" "))
' '
>>> liste
[12, 5, 9, 8]
```

Comment: I think the question was how to remove the `9`, so you'd need to subtract `1` from the index.